# Autolayout: No bounce effect when top edge is pinned to Safe Area

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

A quick question on a weird Auto Layout behaviour in Xcode 9.2, built on Swift 4.

So my scene is built up of a `UIScrollView` pinned to `UIViewController` on all 4 edges. Within the `UIScrollView` is a `UIView` *("Content View")*, also pinned on all 4 edges to its Superview. Now the problem is that, if I have another `UIView` within the Content View, and I pin the top edge to the Safe Area rather than the Superview, the scrolling still works but there is no bounce behaviour when it reaches the top. It simply stops there.

I would like to achieve the behaviour of the rubberbanding effect when the page reaches the top without the inner view clipping off due to iPhone X notch (hence the constraints to safe area at the top rather than Superview) Am I doing something wrong here? Check out the gif below.

First: `UIView` pinned to Superview of Content View - [notice the bounce effect is active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMZk4.gif)

Second: `UIView` pinned to safe area of Content View - [there is no bounce and the scrolling stops immediately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAtwi.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. `UIScrollView` pinned 0(to the safe area) to all 4 edges.
2. `UIView` ("Content View") pinned all 4 edges(to the Superview) and set Equal Heights to the View and align center X.
3. Put the second `UIView` inside the first one and pinned all 4 edges(to the Superview). Note: if you did the first 2 steps it wouldn't even give you the option to pin it to the Safe Area.

Everything is performing as desired, no clipping and you get the bouncing when it reaches the top.